# Configure NTP server and port for systemd-timesyncd

Tags: datetime, ntp

I am trying to configure the NTP server and port for systemd-timesyncd in /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf under [TIME] section with NTP value.

NTP=time.google.com:123

And then I restart systemd-timesyncd but it doesn't sync the time. When I remove the port from the config file, it does.
What can be problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyur here is the perfecr answer for your query.

Don't use semicolon in-between URL and PORT, just give single space.

NTP=time.google.com 123